# Minimum permissions for SQL-based account using Microsoft.Net.Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, permissions, identity

I'm developing an app on ASP.NET MVC, using standard Microsoft.Net.Identity 2.0 for login etc.

First I started with dbo SQL account, now I've added another account with less permissions for better security, grant select on my tables, grant execute on my SPs etc.

But every time I login, I receive an error, for example:

> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

My account does not see `AspNetRoles` table and tries to create it :(

What is the minimum set of permissions for SQL account to use with Identity 2.0?

Comment: I have the same question, although I get the error message `CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'`, since my user only have access to one schema and can't create a new database.